# How do you generate a random sequence of only -1 and 1?

Tags: matlab, random

I want to know how to randomly generate a sequence either -1 or 1.

For example:

```
[1 1 -1 -1] or
[-1 1 -1 1 1 1 1 -1 ] or 
[-1 1 1 -1 1 -1 -1] are what I expect.
```

but `[-1 0 1 -1 -1]` or `[2 1 -1 -1 1 1]` are not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

## Method #1 - Selecting from a small array

You can create a small array that consist of `[-1 1]`, then create random integers that contain either 1 or 2 and index into this sequence:

```
N = 10; %// Number of values in the array

%// Generate random indices
ind = randi(2, N, 1);

%// Create small array
arr = [-1; 1];

%// Get final array
out = arr(ind);
```

## Method #2 - Generate values from a uniform random distribution and threshold

You can also generate random uniformly distributed floating point values, and anything larger than 0.5, you can set to 1, and anything less you can set to -1.

```
N = 10; %// Number of values in the array

%// Generate randomly distributed floating point values
out = rand(N, 1);

%// Find those locations that are >= 0.5
ind = out >= 0.5;

%// Set the right locations to +1/-1
out(ind) = 1;
out(~ind) = -1;
```

## Method #3 - Use trigonometry

You can use the fact that `cos(n*pi)` can either give 1 or -1, depending on what value that `n` is as long as `n` is an integer.  Odd values produce -1 while even values produce 1.  As such, you can generate a bunch of random integers that are either 1 or 2, and calculate `cos(n*pi)`:

```
N = 10; %// Number of values in the array

%// Generate random integers
ind = randi(2, N, 1); 

%// Compute sequence via trigonometry
out = cos(ind*pi);
```

Comment: method #7 is not guaranteed to work for large `N`. `cos(9e7*pi)-1` is not equal to zero.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia - True.  However, if you see the range of values generated, this gives random integers of 1 and 2... and never large values of `N`.  There are, however, `N` values of 1 or 2.... therefore `cos(pi)` and `cos(2*pi)` is well defined.  Please re-read the code and make sure that this is the message being portrayed.  If not, please tell me how to rephrase it.

Comment: there is a method #7? I only see 3.

Comment: There is no method 7! I only see 3 as well?

Comment: Method #7 for N is small, take a coin and flip, Head = 1, Tail = -1; Warning: Success and Mathematically true are Not Guaranteed.

Answer (score 3):

One liner for N elements:

```
2*randi(2, 1, N) - 3
```

or maybe clearer

```
(-1).^randi(2, 1, N)
```

Comment: Second method is quite clever.

Comment: 2nd method is so smart!!